# Python xlwings copy paste with format

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Apologies for no coding provided, this is really a generic question.

I'm using Python xlwings library, and trying to copy a sheet from one workbook to another new workbook, then hard-code the sheet in the newly created workbook. Effectively same as "Copy / Paste Values and source formatting".

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this, and thank you in advance for your help!

edit: someone mentioned that I should include an example. Here it is but it's kind hard to show the format in an Excel file. the following code will copy/paste "sht" into a new workbook but the "new_sht" will contain formulas. I'm trying to hard-code all the values while preserving the number format (eg. with thousands separator, percentage sign, etc)

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('example1.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['sheet1']
new_wb = xw.Book()
new_sht = new_wb.sheets[0]
sht.api.Copy(Before = new_sht.api)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's "really a generic question", you should still provide a [mcve] so people can work out where your code is going wrong.

Comment: @asongtoruin thank you for the comment but it's kinda hard to include a workable example because I'm trying to preserve the format in Excel, but I'll try to update my original post with some coding.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question as I just figured out what I wanted to accomplish.
The following code will hardcode the values while preserve the formatting, since it's essentially pasting value-only to an already formatted area.

```
new_sht.range('A1:C10').value = new_sht.range('A1:C10').value
```